# Не работает функция в PHP

Tags: php

Друзья, всем привет, у меня не работает функция в PHP, что я делаю не так? Я передаю её по ссылке, и вызывая эту функцию, она должна удалять мой массив, но она не работает о_О Буду очень благодарен вам.

```
<?php
    $array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    function myFunctionForDeleteArray(&$array)
    {
        unset($array);
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
    echo "</pre>";

    myFunctionForDeleteArray($array);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: ты делаешь удаление переменной по факту, а не обнуляешь массив......... нужно делать `$array = null;`  или `$array = [];` в зависимости от желаемого результата

Comment: Все это кстати [описано в мануале](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.unset.php#refsect1-function.unset-description)

Comment: Почитал мануал, но не нашёл нужной мне информации, как всё таки сделать функцию, которая будет удалять, например, массив, передаваемый в параметр? Именно функцией unset, ведь вне функции unset отлично справляется с массивами.

Comment: Ну так и используй просто unset. Зачем в функцию все это оборачивать?

Comment: По ссылке можно удалять значения....... сама же переменная находится в другом скоупе..... вне функции переменная всё также существует.....

Comment: @Андрей *"Почитал мануал, но не нашёл нужной мне информации, "*  --- в мануале написано ровно точно как и что нужно сделать, чтобы удалить что-то из глобальной области.... прям по-русски написано

Comment: @Андрей (&$array) что это & за знак?

Comment: @Arcadiy это мы передаем переменную по ссылке

Comment: @u_mulder Спасибо Вам, все получилось по мануалу)))

Answer (score 0):

Получилось решить вопрос благодаря u_mulder, спасибо!)

```
 <?php
    $array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    function myFunctionForDeleteArray(&$array)
    {
        unset($GLOBALS['array']); // удаляет переменную глобальную, а не локальную(в функции) https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.unset.php#refsect1-function.unset-description
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
    echo "</pre>";

    myFunctionForDeleteArray($array);
?>
```

Comment: Такое решение работает, но весьма опасно. Вы хардкодите внутри функции имя переменной снаружи. Если кто-то решит переименовать переменную или использует имя $array для других целей, то функция перестанет работать правильно.